# Division of a part of speech into a separate column in R

Tags: r, tm

I have any corpus, suppose:

```
Clamps for paper-Komus(19 mm, black, 12 pieces per pack)
```

I need to remove digits, abbreviations, prepositions, color, stop words, i.e. after cleansing, only

```
Clamp , paper
```

Moreover, I must put the parts of speech. In other words, in output i must have that format

```
id                        text                                               output
1   Clamps for paper-Komus(19 mm, black, 12 pieces per pack)           clamp    -noun, paper -noun


2   Gel automatic pen Pilot BL-G6-5 blue (thickness  line 0,3mm)       pen  -noun, gel -adj
```

How do that?

```
Refinement
```

In output, we must have no more than two nouns in the nominative case, one noun in the other case and  `THE FIRST` adjective in phrase.
Gel is the first adj.

Comment: Your question is a bit broad I would say, since it covers pattern removal via regex, stopword removal, POS tagging and data formatting. I would recommend to split it up in several questions and also to read some package vignettes, e.g., `tm`, `koRpus`, `text2vec`, `stringi`, etc., some tutorials on the web and corresponding answers hero on SO regarding the issues you want to have covered. What have you tried so far, could you share some code?

Comment: By the way, POS tagging must be applied *before* you remove all stopwords, and it generates a lot of data (think about it - for each word there'll be a whole lot of metadata, often in in nested structures, that  you then need to filter) - good luck.

Comment: @ManuelBickel, i don't have the code, cause i don't know how perform this task

Comment: This question appears to be a duplicate of [Tagging Part of Speech for a Particular Word in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35772720/tagging-part-of-speech-for-a-particular-word-in-r).

Comment: Could you please specify the output more in detail? In your example in the second line you want pen and gel. The latter is used as an adjective, however, you do not want automatic, which is also an adjective here. How do you know which parts of speech, e.g. which adjectives, you want as output. Could you clarify this, please.

Comment: @ManuelBickel,  this point, I missed. I edited the post, please look at.

Comment: Ok, this is doable. Please start trying the code given in linked answer that marks your question as duplicate and update your answer with the steps you tried and were exactly you struggled. Then it would be possible to aid you with specific individual issues.

Comment: @ManuelBickel, the problem is that it does not mark my question as a duplicate, in a related topic, topic starter is interested in the pos for all words, I also need to leave up to two nouns in the nominative case and the first adjective.

Comment: your question is not an exact duplicate, but almost. in pos tagging you usually tag all words and only then remove undesired parts. hence, you should use the code (or parts of it) of the existing answer on your data, show us the results or what does not work, then we can support you.